# webdrivr click the button which will call Javascript can't work

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

(1) html:

```
<table class="title_button" onclick="onSave();" onmouseout="this.className='title_button'; save_moveout();" onmouseover="this.className='title_button_hi'; save_movein();" title="Copy Running-config to Startup-config">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="title_btn_save" src="https://192.168.100.116/image/title_btn_alert.gif">
            </td>
            <td id="title_save">Save</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(2) Webdriver Java:

tried these two ways both can't work.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("title_save")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[8]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2][@id='title_save'")).click();
```

(3) Exception:

```
webdriver element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to click the `td` element, but the actual "clickable" element here is the `table`:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("title_button")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like element you try to click in disabled and click operation cannot be performed to this element.

Try to perform click operation on another element e.g. on :

```
driver.findElement(By.css(".title_button tr")).click();
```